# Planar graph and bipartite sub graph

Tags: planar-graphs, bipartite-graphs

Trying to figure out a proof of the following:

> Let $G=(V,E)$ be a planar graph. Prove that $G$ contains a bipartite sub-graph with at least $\dfrac23|E|$ edges.

Any tips?

Note: Found [this proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/289537/show-that-every-graph-g-has-a-bipartite-subgraph-with-at-least-half-of-the-edg) for $\dfrac12|E|$ but not $\dfrac23|E|$.

Comment: What have you attempted so far?