# Question about the proof of every graph $G$, $G$ contains a bipartite subgraph $H$ such that $|E(H)| > 1/2|E(G)|$

Tags: graph-theory, bipartite-graphs

Part of this proof involves choosing $v \in V(G)$ for $n(G) > 2$ that is not incident to all of $E(G)$. This is because at most two vertices can be incident to all of $E(G)$. Why is that last statement true? I'm sure it's trivial, but I can't wrap my head around it.

Comment: Well, if $G$ is the complete graph it does not contain bipartite (induced) subgraphs. On the other hand, if $G$ is the graph with no edge, how can it contain a bipartite subgraph with more than half of its edges (the edges of H).

Comment: Oh, do you mean that every graph $G$ contains a bipartite subgraph $H$ such that $|E(H)|\geq \frac{1}{2}|E(G)|$? In this case, you mean $H$ as a subgraph or as an induced subgraph?

Comment: @DaríoG Read section 1.3 in West's *Introduction to Graph Theory*.

Comment: Yes, except the strict inequality holds as well.

Comment: It seems to be a duplicated of this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/289537/show-that-every-graph-g-has-a-bipartite-subgraph-with-at-least-half-of-the-edg and this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/210601/in-a-graph-the-vertices-can-be-partitioned-v-v-1-cup-v-2-so-that-at-most-half

Comment: I don't see how the second one is a duplicate. The first one doesn't deal with the specific part of the proof I'm concerned about.

Comment: You are right. I was just reading the title of the question, not the question itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reason: Every edge has only two end points.

Comment: So if every edge were incident to vertices, they can only be to two because one vertex for each endpoint for each edge? Correct?

Comment: @dirtysocks45 Yes.