# Reducing a graph to be $k$-colourable

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

For a given random graph $G = (V, E)$ and a natural number $k$ I should develop a method for reducing the set of edges $E(G)$ s.t. the graph becomes $k$ colourable but the reduced set $E'$ of edges fulfils the equality: $|E'| \geq |E| \cdot \dfrac{k-2}{k}$. I should use probabilistic methods, but I don't even understand why it should always be possible to find such an $E'$ fulfilling this inequality. Could someone maybe help me with this?

Comment: You should be able to do this with $|E'| \ge |E| \cdot \frac{k-1}{k}$, too. (You might have seen the $k=2$ case, where we find a bipartite subgraph with at least half the edges; the general idea is similar.)

Comment: @MishaLavrov I haven't seen this case so far. Could you give me any reference or hint how to develop such a probabilistic algorithm?

Comment: It's appeared on MSE before: see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/210601/in-a-graph-the-vertices-can-be-partitioned-v-v-1-cup-v-2-so-that-at-most-half?noredirect=1&lq=1) for two solutions, one which is direct and one by the probabilistic method.

Comment: @MishaLavrov I'm given the hint that the expected runtime should be $O(|V| + |E|)$, meaning I should develop a las Vegas algorithm. The proposed algorithm in the solution doesn't seem to be a Las Vegas algorithm however. But maybe I'm missing something...

Comment: If you're looking for an algorithm with a guarantee on runtime, I'd actually use the deterministic solution over the probabilistic one. You *can* derandomize the probabilistic one, but it's trickier.

Comment: @MishaLavrov it should be an algorithm that guarantees for correctness but has the desired expected runtime (so the runtime isn't guaranteed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want a *random* algorithm that satisfies the weaker guarantee $|E'| \ge \frac{k-2}{k}|E|$ with a good expected runtime, then we can generalize the random approach to the bipartition problem. Choose a random partition $V = V_1 \cup \dots \cup V_k$ by assigning each vertex independently at random to one part; then delete all edges within each part $V_i$.

You should be able to show that the expected number of edges deleted is $\frac1 k|E|$; hence you can get at most $\frac2k|E|$ deleted edges after (in expectation) a constant number of trials.

---

I think this is a bit silly. A deterministic algorithm that makes the better guarantee $|E'| \ge \frac{k-1}{k}|E|$ in $O(|V|+|E|)$ worst-case running time is to just go through all the vertices one at a time, and place each vertex $v$ in the part $V_i$ that contains the fewest number of $v$'s neighbors.

Comment: the first approach you mentioned is exactly what I'm currently trying to prove probabilistically. I see that a deterministic solution is preferable and will thus try to prove the latter one also.

Comment: I don't really see how the expected number of edges is 1/k * |E|...

Comment: @Sebastian What's the probability that both endpoints of an edge end up in the same part? Now multiply that by the number of edges.

Comment: but this algorithm only gives us a set of edges $E$ that fulfils the inequality of the OP when considering the expected value, didn't the OP want an algorithm that definitely finds such a set and not just in the expected value or do we just let the algorithm run until it finds such a set and the expected runtime is then $O(|E| + |V|)$ ? Because such a set exists for sure, as you showed.

Comment: @Sebastian The Las Vegas algorithm is to repeat until you find the set. But to get an expected runtime of $O(|E|+|V|)$, we weaken the condition. We repeat until we get a partition with at most $\frac{2}{k}|E|$ deleted edges, which is twice the expected value. By Markov's inequality, this happens with probability at least $\frac12$.

Comment: wow, this is interesting. Thanks a lot for the quick answer!

Comment: @MishaLavrov but how do I get from $1/2$ to $O(|E| + |V|)$. Sorry if my questions seem stupid, but I don't really know how one compute the expected runtime. Doesn't one has to somehow use the geometric distribution since were are interested in the expected number of times we have to run the algorithm so that we get a set of edges that fulfils the given inequality?

Comment: If the expected number of times we repeat the algorithm is constant, then you should just check that each time you repeat the algorithm, it takes $O(|E|+|V|)$ steps to do everything.

Comment: @MishaLavrov ok, so then I must have misunderstood something. Thanks again!

Comment: @Sebastian you are indeed using the Geometric distribution, with success probability $1/2$.